# Minimum changes to obtain an alternating sequence

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming

I've been studying dynamic programming lately and came across a problem that is, I believe (might be wrong, though), a modification of the classic longest alternating subsequence (LAS) problem.

But instead of asking you what is the maximum length, this problem asks what is the minimum number of changes you would have to do to any `V[i]` element such that the whole input array becomes an alternating sequence. Changes can only be subtractions, not additions.

Example: `2 5 8 6 1 2`

In this case the minimum number is `1`: you can make the `8` a `4`, for example.

The answer could be `0` as well if the whole sequence is already alternating.

For solving the LAS, I know we need to retain in `DP[i][0]` the size of the longest alternating subsequence ending at `i` for which the last element is greater than the previous one and in `DP[i][1]` the same when the last element is lesser than its previous. And we build this by iterating from 1 to `i-1`.

But how can I find the changes I'd need to make to turn the whole sequence into an alternating one?

Comment: I'm not convinced it's similar to the LAS problem precisely because we need to make the *entire* sequence alternating.

Comment: Could definitely be the case. I just noticed some kind of resemblance, but it might indeed have nothing to do with it.

Comment: I'm also not sure it needs to be solved with DP;  correct me if I'm wrong, but you want the final sequence to either be like $a[0]>a[1]<a[2]>\cdots$ or like $a[0]<a[1]>a[2]<\cdots$.  In the first case, it should never make sense to decrease the even-indexed elements. In the second case it should never make sense to decrease the odd-indexed elements.  Then our strategy might be: do the least possible to get into each of the two cases, and see which of the two yields a smaller number of decreases.

Comment: Hmm, not exactly. Let's take `10 20 13 14 20 15 14`. `20` has index an even index, but decreasing it to anything lower than `14` makes the whole sequence alternating.

Comment: That's the second case I referred to:  where you want to end up with $a[0]<a[1]>a[2]<\cdots$, in which case it doesn't make sense to decrease the odd-indexed elements (so you would only possibly decrease the even indexed elements). Your suggestion indeed avoids decreasing any odd-indexed elements

Comment: That's right, I didn't realize the example sequence did not start as in your first case. I can't think of other counter-examples so let's assume that indeed your observation is correct: no decreasing of odd-indexed elements if `a[0] < a[1]` and vice-versa. I'm still lost at the strategy you mentioned though. How do you do "the least possible" for each case?

Comment: stackexchange is telling me to avoid an extended discussion, but basically, in case 2, you iterate through all even indices and decreases them (if applicable) to the minimum of the neighbors, minus 1.  10 is already good, 13 too, then 20 gets taken to 13; 14 is good, done.

Comment: Indeed we can be certain the number of decreases required we obtain that way is the minimum one if only even-indices can be decreased. I was under the impression that at some point a seemingly-looking-worse-choice ends up being the best one after all, and that usually smells like DP. But yeah if you restrict odd/even indices then that's no longer the case. I'm gonna try to code your idea tomorrow and get back to you so that you can post this as the accepted answer if everything is OK. Thanks and sorry for the extended chat!